# Are Ignite Custom SQL Functions executed on the server node or on the client node?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

When invoked from a client node, are Ignite Custom SQL Functions executed on the server node or on the client node?

I think they are always executed on the server node before returning the values to the client node (in the case where the query is being executed from an ignite client node against a distributed cache on the ignite server node).

Is the above understanding correct? If so, i understand this is invoked & works at row level and that means i can even look up another cache inside the function to generate even a 'compute column'. Is that okay to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, the [SQL functions](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/custom-sql-func) are always executed on server nodes. But I would be careful about accessing other caches or records from inside the function or generating any values. The function should be used for stateless scenarios because it can be executed more than once for a single record if the cluster topology changes while the function's query is being executed.

Share more details about your use case and we might suggest more suitable Ignite APIs for your task.

Comment: Thanks @dmagda for the confirmation & clarification with useful info. I only intended to use if in a stateless fashion, but i did not realize it can be executed more than once for a single record in the case of cluster topology change...on the use cases i will reply once again with the details.

Comment: One correction: it is possible for a client to execute sql functions in one case. 1) It is a thick client initiating the query (so that it is the query's reducer node) 2) The function falls into the reduce step of the query. But normally functions fall into the map part, so yes, they'll be executed on the server.